# Voltage-boosted switching boost converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost, zener, tvs, snubber

I refer to my previous question which may be found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282925/a-switching-boost-converter-biasing-a-tube-preamp-saturation-issue). With the LT1172 the highest output voltage of the booster is about 60 V, or slightly more. Now I need more, say 100 V.

Linear technologies' [Application Note 19](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an19fc.pdf) reports an interesting voltage-boosted boost converter (see page 43) which makes use of a tapped inductor. But, the formulae are reported without an extensive explanation, and I am unable to reconstruct it. I am unsure about how to estimate the proper inductor specifications, especially in view of the need for a snubber, and when I try to calculate the value for the snubber resistor I fall into nonsense values, such as zero or negative ones.

In conclusion, I would need some advice on this topic, and possibly a reference for further reading.

EDIT: I have advanced somewhat, thanks to the readings suggested in the comments. Now I am trying to design the snubber. I am trying with a Zener diode, but I need some help with it: I need it to be about 50 V, with the ability to sustain repetitive current spikes of a bit more than 1 A, but from my computation the average power over the Zener seems to be less than half a W. I have not been able to locate such a diode.

From further investigation, I am considering Transient Voltage Suppressors: is this reasonable or are they only suitable for extraordinary events? Are these diodes rated for repetitive current spikes? (As far as I have seen, in Zener data sheets the surge current is specified as "non repetitive.")

Comment: For high step-up ratios, I'd look into a flyback topology.  That also has the advantage of it being possible to completely isolate the high voltage.  That can be a good thing when the voltage is high enough to hurt or kill someone.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But I think a flyback requires a much bigger transformer. Is that true?

Comment: Perhaps a little bigger than the inductor in a equivalent supply.  However, the energy per pulse is still the same, so the same core size.  On the other hand, consider the extra size of boosting the boost converter.

Comment: Thank you, I will consider this topology as well. In any case, I would be glad to find out some further reading about the tapped-inductor topology. The flyback seems to be much easier to find in textbooks.

Comment: I don't really know what you meant by "tapped inductor".  Maybe that is the same as a flyback converter using a auto-transformer.  That's also a viable way to get high step-up ratios, but without isolation.

Comment: Yes, as far as I have understood (also from a talk with a transformer manufacturer) a tapped inductor is exactly a small autotransformer. So maybe I may try to start from the flyback topology, derive equations for it, and adapt the procedure to the tapped inductor? In any case, from a preliminary search I haven't found a textbook with the autotransformer flyback topology.

Comment: Here is another article about the same concept, it may fill it some of the details: [Small, High-Voltage Boost Converters](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1109). Give the output transistor some voltage margin by selecting the turn ratio and you may not even need the snubber because the output serves as a snubber (but not perfectly reflected to the tap).

Comment: This might help you: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273517256_Double_tapped-inductor_boost_converter   It covers the various configurations and relatively detailed guidelines.

Comment: @rioraxe How does the output limit the tap voltage in any way?

Comment: If the transformer is perfect, then the voltages of the two windings are locked in a ratio. In the flyback setup, the leakage of the primary would cause the voltage to pulse higher than the perfect case. In the cascaded/tapped setup, when the tap voltage wants to go higher, it pushes on the secordary/cascaded winding, therefore the output (in particular the output capacitor) serves as snubber. The bonus is that the energy goes to the output and is not wasted.

Comment: @rioraxe Thank you, I will think about it. It would be useful to have a detailed description of how to calculate the needed voltage margin.

Comment: @Enrico I saw your other question. For a flyback, the snubber design is usually based on a guess. For example, the leakage inductance is 1 or 2% of the total inductor. I would call that a second order effect. For the tapped version, which I think is clearly superior for your stated application, the leakage pulse voltage would depends on 3rd order effect, i.e. guesses on top of a guess. But, if you look at figure 11 of the article I linked to, in the middle gray waveform, you can see the peak of the pulse is 50% extra, that is without a snubber.

Comment: The article also seems to use 2/3 of the power switch rating as the design voltage for the high level. So a reasonable approach would be to use 2/3 of the power switch rating for the design voltage, put in a provision for a snubber that may not be needed and populated. Using a TVS is OK, you want that 2/3 margin anyway because TVS voltage is not very precise.

Comment: @rioraxe Thank you for the kind reply. Honestly I don't understand your classification in 2nd and 3rd order effects. I am in contact with an inductor manufacturer and he says that with so small an inductor (we are talking of a few tens uH, for discontinuous operation and light load) the efficiency cannot be more than about 90%, which means a leakage inductance equal to 10% of the primary.

Comment: @rioraxe Besides this, figure 11 in that article is about a transformer-based approach. As for the margin, yes, I need a working voltage on the switch of no more than 30 V when the breakdown is at more than 60 V, that because a TVS has a wide range between its stand-off and clamp voltages. I also simulated my circuit with LTSpice, and it seems the snubber is definitely needed. I have to trust simulations, because I don't want to just try and run the risk of breaking down switches.

Comment: @rioraxe Lastly, I called LT's Engineers and asked about TVS's (whether they are suitable for this application). They say they are definitely OK. I will try with a TVS by Littelfuse having a stand-off voltage of about 30 V and a maximum clamp voltage of about 60 V, and the ability of sustaining a peak current of more than 8 A.

Comment: Figure 9 represents the "transformer" approach. It takes a transformer and connects the two windings in series, so it is equivalent to a tapped inductor. I think your conclusion is also that some testing is necessary to optimize the snubber.

Comment: @rioraxe Ok, sorry, you're right, I missed figure 9. It's just a tapped inductor called transformer (it's an autotransformer), if I am not wrong again. And yes, the snubber may only be optimized by taking into account non-idealities of the switch and the snubber itself, I think, so some testing should be done. But if I manage to get a working prototipe, I think I will stick there. If you'd like to discuss further, I'd move to chat.